# Update, Add rows to a datatable VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataset

I have tried so hard to solve my problem, here's what I'm trying to do:

- I have an XML file that I load into a dataset("ds") using `ReadXML`,
  several tables are populated in to the dataset, the one I'm concerned
  about is ("SalesReceiptRet") and I'll refer to it as the source
  table.
- I have another table in MS Access database, I load it into the same
  dataset using `OleDBAdapter.Fill`, into a datatable named ("dtTarget") 
  and the adapter's name is ("dbAdapter").

I want to go through all the records in the source table, lookup a field called ("TxnID") to locate the record in the target table. If it does not exist, add it, if it does do another validation and overwrite/update it using the source's row.

here's the code:

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    'Initialize command builder
    Dim dbCommandBuilder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(dbAdapter)

    'Set the primary keys
    ds.Tables("dtTarget").PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {ds.Tables("dtTarget").Columns("TxnID")}

    'Find rows
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim lookupRow As DataRow

    For Each dr In ds.Tables("SalesReceiptRet").Rows

        lookupRow = ds.Tables("dtTarget").Rows.Find(dr.Item(0))
        'If the a row with a similar TxnID exists, do the following validation
        If Not (lookupRow Is Nothing) Then
            If lookupRow.Item(8).ToString <> "Regular" Then
                'do something here to overwrite/update the matching row
            End If
        Else
            'If the row does not exist, import it
            ds.Tables("dtTarget").ImportRow(dr)
        End If

    Next

    'Update Access
    dbAdapter.Update(ds, "dtTarget")
    dbConnection.Close()


End Sub
```

Perhaps I need to mention that both tables have exact column names except for Access "dtTarget" has additional ones, which does not seem to be causing problem at least with the import row.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: What is your code doing right now?  Is it not updating?  Is it not importing?  Is it throwing an error?

Comment: It's importing fine but not updating because I haven't written anything for it to do so

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started,

For more help with Access and the insert /Update on the adapter see this link 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/958e6d51-725a-4649-8fc0-79a831f8f37e

```
Dim connStr As String = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=(local);Database=MyNewTest;Uid=user; Pwd=******;"
Dim selectCmd As String = "select * from IdentityTest"
Dim dbAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(selectCmd, connStr)
dbAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = True

'code here to fille up your adapter
'build the insert and update comand on the adapter
Dim InsertCommans As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO <table> (field1,field2,field3,field4) Values (@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4)")
Dim UpdateCommans As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE <table> SET <field> = @Value WHERE <field> = @TxnID")

'Set the primary keys
Dim ds As DataSet
ds.Tables("dtTarget").PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {ds.Tables("dtTarget").Columns("TxnID")}

'assign our datatables
Dim oDtSource As DataTable = ds.Tables("SalesReceiptRet")
Dim oDtTarget As DataTable : dbAdapter.Fill(oDtTarget)

'for each TxnID in our source table
For Each dr As DataRow In oDtSource.Rows

'get the rows in the target that match to the current source table row taxnid [colname] = TxnID
Dim oRowsInTarget As DataRow() = oDtTarget.Select("[" & oDtTarget.Columns(0).ColumnName & "] = " & dr("TxnID"))
'if there is a match (assuming there will only be one) and the column 8 contents (this is column 9 in reality)
'dowes not equal "Regular" then proceed to run the ole adapter update statement else insert
If oRowsInTarget.Count > 0 AndAlso Not oRowsInTarget(0)(8).ToString <> "Regular" Then
    'perform our update
    'you have thematching TxnId in dr("TxnID")
    'I think you can configure an insert and update statment on the Ole adapter connected to access
    'EXEC UPDATE ON THE ADAPTER
ElseIf oRowsInTarget.Count > 0 Then
    'EXEC INSERT ON THE ADAPTER
End If
Next
```

Comment: Hello Andre and thank you,
I was trying to use one of the built-in methods of the class as if I'm gonna write the UPDATE sql command it will be very very long .. I have more than 60 columns.